# mysql query to join multi tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 4 tables like this:

**Users**

```
id | name | type | user | pass | active_work | word_limit | max_word_limit | photo | note
--------------
 1  | test1 | 3 | user1 | pass1 | 0 | 10 | 15 | photo1 | note1
 2  | test2 | 4 | user2 | pass2 | 3 | 12 | 22 | photo2 | note2
 3  | test3 | 4 | user3 | pass3 | 1 | 12 | 22 | photo3 | note3
 4  | test4 | 3 | user4 | pass4 | 2 | 12 | 22 | photo4 | note4
 5  | test5 | 3 | user5 | pass5 | 2 | 12 | 22 | photo5 | note5
 6  | test6 | 3 | user6 | pass6 | 3 | 12 | 22 | photo6 | note6
```

**vacation** (my problem is here, with table !)

```
id | user_id | from_date | till_date
--------------
 3 | 1 | 16-03-2017 | 22-03-2017
 4 | 1 | 25-03-2017 | 27-03-2017
```

**tr_cat**

```
id | user_id | cat_id
--------------
 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 2 | 1
 1 | 1 | 2
 2 | 2 | 2
```

**tr_type**

```
id | user_id | type_id
--------------
 1  | 1 | 1
 2  | 2 | 1
 2  | 2 | 2
```

and maybe you need to know whats `type` and `cat`

**cat**

```
id | name
--------------
 1  | English
 2  | Arabic
 3  | Germany
```

**type**

```
id | name
--------------
 1  | normal
 2  | special
```

**user_type**

```
id | name
--------------
 1  | admin
 2  | member
 3  | freelancer
 4  | full time
```

**Description :**
All tables are connected.

I try to select user which available in `tr_cat` and `tr_type` with special `cat_id` and `type_id` (means can translate special language and type)

for ex : `select * from users,tr_cat,tr_type where tr_type.user_id = users.id AND tr_cat.user_id = user.id AND tr_cat.id = 1 AND tr_type.id = 1`

but also i want `user.id` NOT EXISTS in `vacation` list or if row exists with that user.id `TODAY DATE` NOT BETWEEN `from_date` and `till_date` (means user available at work !)

and finally i want to order by `user.type` and `user.active_work`

for create query in my project i use from [PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) ,anyway if you can help i understand normal query  too :-"

here is my code :

```
    $db->where ("(u.type = ? or u.type = ?)", Array(3,4));
    $db->join("vacation v", $today." NOT BETWEEN v.from_date and v.till_date", "LEFT"); 
    // problem here  i don't know how to join this tables
    $db->joinWhere("vacation v", "v.user_id=u.id");// OR User ID Not EXISTS
    $db->join("tr_cat c", "c.user_id=u.id", "LEFT");
    $db->joinWhere("tr_cat c", "c.id", $cat);
    $db->join("tr_type t", "t.user_id=u.id", "LEFT");
    $db->joinWhere("tr_type t", "t.id", $type);
    $tr_list = $db->get ("users u", null, "u.id, u.name, u.type, u.user, u.active_work, u.word_limit, u.max_word_limit");
```

anyone can help me for this join ?

I want to get result something like this

```
 id | name | type | user | active_work | word_limit | max_word_limit
 --------------
 3  | test3 | 4 | user3 | 1 | 12 | 22 
 2  | test2 | 4 | user2 | 3 | 12 | 22
 5  | test5 | 3 | user5 | 2 | 12 | 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u JOIN tr_cat c ON u.id = c.user_id
JOIN tr_type t ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE c.cat_id = <some_id> AND t.type_id = <some_id>
AND u.id NOT IN (
 SELECT user_id 
 FROM vacation
 WHERE now() BETWEEN from_date AND to_date
);
```